# add a random number to dataframe with input from tKinter

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

A random number shall be added to a DataFrame in its calculation. For each row a different number. The range for this number comes from an `Entry` from a tKinter GUI, the calculation: `df = (names + random_number + '&' + self.info.get())` (where `info` is not related)

The calculation of `random_number` is

```
range_start = int(self.number_range_start.get())
range_end = int(self.number_range_end.get())
random_number = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(range_start,range_end)
```

I also tried it with `random_number = random.randint(range_start,range_end)`
Though with all the different versions I experimented with I always got an error for either passing a String instead of an Integer or vice versa, even when I added `str()` or `int()` I still got these errors. With the `pd.DataFrame` version I get "DataFrame constructor not properly called!"-Error

Now I guessed it may miss the length of the dataframe and added `range_length` as third argument with numphy by `range_length = names.count()` which doesn't work as well.

I am pretty new to Pyhton and just can't figure out why its not working.

I made a little test function without the dataframe calculation and its working:

```
range_start = int(self.number_range_start.get())
range_end = int(self.number_range_end.get())
random_number = random.randint(range_start,range_end)
print(random_number)
```

Edit: I finally found a way that it works (by this code: `df = (names + str(random.randint(range_start, range_end)) + '&' + self.domain.get())`) Though it doesn't what I want it to do. It adds the same number to every row instead of for each row a new random number.
Would I have to asign with a for loop a new number for each row or is there another way? Or could I somehow add `pd.DataFrame` again and let it do it automatically?

Comment: Edit: `names` already is a dataframe with several thousand rows.

Comment: Should I shorten the question and make it a new one since it doesn't really hit the acutal topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I comfirm your question is a bit confused and would have worth some improvements.
As I understand you want to make a random integer column, convert it to strings, then concatenate this column to every columns of a string dataframe.

Call `randint()` to make a random integer column, giving it the same length that the dataframe with the size argument.

Convert this column to strings by calling the method `.astype(str)`

Then concatenate this column to every columns with the method `add()`

This is what I did below :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':['AA','BB','CC'],'col2':['DD','EE','FF']})

col=np.random.randint(1,5,size=len(df)).astype(str)

df2=df.add(col,axis=0)

print(df2)
```

It gives the ouptut :

```
  col1 col2
0  AA3  DD3
1  BB4  EE4
2  CC3  FF3
```

Comment: Yes, when writing I wasn't sure where excatly the problem was. Great you could answer it nevertheless!

Comment: astype(str) did it. Now its all working fine! The size argument is only possible with numpy, like you did.
Thanks for your help!